# MySql query cache settings

Tags: php, sql, mysql

How can I set the query cache of MySql?

My "my.ini" file doesn't contain the variable `mysql_query_type` or `mysql_query_size` at all...

How are these set?

Can they be set from PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may enable query caching by altering the `query-cache-type` value in your MySQL configuration file. You may not change it from PHP, however you may clear it by sending the following query to MySQL: `RESET QUERY CACHE`.

Answer (score 2):

The mysql query cache size configuration is usually located in the `my.ini`. Since it is a server configuration, it usually shouldn't be allowed that scripts like php change its configuration. If I remember correctly, the mysql query cache is usually on unless you haven't compiled mysql without it.

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-configuration.html) are more detailed information on how it works, how it is configured, and what initialization variables are to be used.

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/dynamic-system-variables.html) are more detailed information on how you can modify the behaviour using dynamic system variables.

I haven't used phpmyadmin for a long time, so I can't answer on how these values are easily accessible. With `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%query%';` it should be easy to access them anyway.

Comment: can I use phpMyAdmin for this? and what section under my.ini should I set it?

Comment: I've added a bit more detail into my initial reply.